# Few UIViewControllers with one Tab bar controller - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create simple iOS app, which allow users order some products from my shop. I have very big problem with one thing, namely:

After log in, user will go to ViewController with list of products. At the bottom of this controller I want to add TabBar with only two buttons "Your cart" [which will have badge with amount of products in cart] and "Settings". The problem is, that I want to add this tab bar on my all viewcontrollers (Products list, Product details, Terms of use, etc.) - not only for "Your cart" and "Settings". Initially I thought that I can add one TabBarController, to this controller I wanted to link all application ViewControllers and hide unnecessary buttons. After tests it seems that it's not good way to do this type of functionality.

Firstly, I got error when I want to delete some items in TabBarController:

> Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not
>   allowed.

Secondly I think, that if I remove some buttons from tab bar controller, I will remove links to viewcontrollers at the same time.

On Android, i use xml to build custom TabBar, and fragments to change content of application.

Are somebody is able to tell me how it should be done on iOS?

Kindly Regards,
Oskar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a UIToolBar, not a UITabBar - tab bars assume they contain whatever is on screen and cannot be embedded in views very easily, where UIToolBar can be placed wherever you like in a view, in multiple views.

You should really study up on the basics of UINavigationController though, which you probably want wrapping your entire application.